# Ubuntu 18.04: Put window into screen corner

Tags: gnome, 18.04, window, tiling

I have an external 4K display on my laptop with plenty of space, that I usually use like four individual monitors in a grid. So I tend to put one window in every corner of the screen (IDE, terminal, browser, etc.). In Ubuntu 16.04, Unity offered to option to automatically place windows there by moving them to the screen edge or screen corner, so you had 8 options on where to put a window just by moving it around (top left corner, top half, top right corner, right half, etc.). Now in Ubuntu 18.04, only the Windows-like behaviour seems to be implemented with maximize (top edge), left half (left edge) and right half (right edge). Is there a way to get the additional areas back as in Unity?

Thanks!

Best regards,
Philipp

Comment: Alternatively, you can still install & use Unity. It's in the official repository.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

After writing the question, a similar one popped up: [Resize 4 windows to occupy the screen without overlap on Ubuntu 18.04](https://askubuntu.com/a/1054581/854337)

The keyword was "tiling" and the GNOME extension [ShellTile](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/657/shelltile/) does exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 4):

GNOME Extension of preference for me is:
[Put Windows](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/39/put-windows/)

It's supposed to be a replacement for the Unity functionality you mentioned.

Comment: It works much better then previous method in Unity. For ex. it supports 3 sizes for every position! I like it a lot

Comment: I've installed it, but it doesn't seem to be working.

Comment: @AlexejMagura, you might need to `log out` and `log in` (at least that worked for me). Also, how dit you install it? I installed from Ubuntu Software, search `Put Windows`.  Then you can use `Super + Numpad` (e.g. Numpad #1 will put the screen in the bottom left corener)

Comment: It is utterly crazy that @toto_tico's comment here is the only documentation I could find on how to actually use this plugin. Nothing on the extension page, nothing on the GitHub page it links to.

Answer (score 3):

Use [ShellTIle](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/657/shelltile/)

First enable extensions with: (the prefix chrome is not related to chromium, it works on any window)

```
sudo apt install chrome-gnome-shell
```

Then go to [ShellTIle](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/657/shelltile/)

And click ON

Comment: I don't have an option to click ON, what do I do?

Answer (score 0):

Try [gtile](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/28/gtile/), window tiling suited for both landscape and portrait mode.

It has helpful shortcuts (Super+Alt+2, Super+Alt+8, etc) and presets (2x2 4k landscape mode, custom 1x2 portrait mode, etc).